# Vue prevent enter strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, vue-router

I have a `Vue3` app that has a form in it. The app also uses the `vue` router. In the form, I have a `textarea`. I've added a `@submit.prevent` to the form, but then I hit enter in the `textarea` the page redirects to its parent component. When I click the button it behaves correctly. Only when I hit the enter key in the `textarea` the redirect occurs.

A minimal example looks like this:

```js
<template>
  <div class="">
    <form @submit.prevent="validate()" class="flex flex-col">
      <textarea
        class="mt-0 block w-full px-0.5 bg-white text-black border-0 border-b-2 border-primary focus:ring-0 focus:border-other"
        rows="2"
      >
      </textarea>
      <button type="submit">Test</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  setup() {
    const validate = () => {
      console.log(`check if validated`);
    };

    return {
      validate,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have this component wrapped by router-link?

Comment: It is wrapped in a component as a child within a router-view. No router-links in sight, as far as I can see, but I'll double check